# React conditional rendering component test cases jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Can anyone help me to write a test case for conditional rendering components using jest and enzyme?

```
{this.state.addingNewContent ?
          <AddContent
            contentId={this.state.contentId}
            added={this.addContentHandler}
            meta={option}
            closeAddContent={this.closeAddContent}
            assignedData={this.state[option.name]} />
          : <Lock
            lock={this.state.isLocked}
            lockedBy={this.state.lockedBy}
            clicked={() => this.toggleModal(true, 'lock')}>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for conditional rendering, you need to mock state like

```
import AddContent from '../COMPONENT';
import Lock from '../COMPONENT'

it('should render AddContent component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  wrapper.setState({ addingNewContent: true });
  const component = wrapper.find(AddContent);
  expect(component.length).toBe(1);
});

it('should render Lock Component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />);
  wrapper.setState({ addingNewContent: true });
  const component = wrapper.find(Lock);
  expect(component.length).toBe(1);
});
```

It's better to have separate test cases.

Comment: For the else case?

Comment: i am getting error like this : 
expect(received).toBe(expected) 
    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

Comment: MyComponent is your class component name.

Comment: I am still getting this error expect(received).toBe(expected) Expected: 1 Received: 0

Comment: could you add your state code of the class component

Comment: constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      addingNewContent: false
    }
}
Here is the state code for that. @skdroid